# Why are my sniper rifles overheating in Mass Effect?

Tags: mass-effect

I just started my second playthrough of the original Mass Effect on PC, and every time I fire a sniper rifle it overheats. This happens regardless of which sniper rifle I have equipped (one is listed at 1.2 shots before overheat, the other 1.3. I'm not very far in yet).

Perhaps I'm simply misremembering, but I believe in my previous playthrough I could fire, wait for heat to dissipate, then fire again without overheating. Now it just overheats after every shot.

Is this a bug? Is there some debuff on me that's causing this? Or something else?

Comment: From what I remember, most of the earlier sniper rifles overheated after a single shot until you start using cooling upgrades on them. It's been years so i'm not 100% on this.

Comment: I considered that, but it seems weird to list them as 1.2 shots to overheat if it's just 1...

Comment: Yeah that is weird. I don't remember if character class or skill points in weapons had anything to do with it either

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that shots/overheat stat takes into account the attachments on the weapon. I would still do as GodEmperorDune said and check the attachments as I remember testing this to see if I could force and overheat in one shot on a sniper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you're misremembering - unless the weapons don't cool down after they've fired one shot. @GodEmperorDune is right, the sniper rifles would generally overheat after one shot despite having 1.2+ shots before cooldown until later in the game where weapons and upgrades got better. Weapons not cooling down is either from an Engineer using [Sabotage](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Decryption#Sabotage) or the "[eternal overheat](https://forum.bioware.com/topic/145276-the-overheat-bug-and-how-to-fix-it/)" bug.

Comment: I would like to add that the ammo type is also a significant factor too